# CommandBar Buttons Hover

Tags: office-ui-fabric, fluent-ui, fluentui-react, commandbar

I am using the CommandBar Component to display links. (The buttons are href links).
I want to remove the underline from buttons when hover. Is it possible? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A0oEx.png)

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui#/controls/web/commandbar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove the underline of a button when hover, maybe you can do something like this

```
button: hover{
text-decoration: none;
}
```

Let me know if that worked for you